# Generate or fill cell data based on another dataset excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've a data set that shows;

- employee name
- date
- time work started
- time work ended

[image: dataset]

Now I am trying to have a report like sheet where I can select a certain employee name from a list of employees to view his/her time attended for a particular month.

[image: report]

I tried vlookup but went no where since I need to lookup by two columns plus a row.

Is this possible? without macros or vba.
Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that one employee has two different 'time in' or 'time out' on one day, in other words: are name and date unique identifiers?

Comment: name and date will be unique. there won't be two different 'time in' or 'time out'

Comment: Have you tried using sumifs?

Comment: You can create a pivot table with keeping employee name in the filter.

Comment: actually it's not that I am trying to achieve some work task here. I would like to learn how to do this so that it would improve my excel skills - that's why no vba came in there.

pivot would help I figured too, but is there a formula-way?

Comment: sumifs would be simplest

Comment: @Roosz0rd
just tried sumifs.
it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since name and date are unique identifiers it is possible to use the sumifs function.

For ‘time in’ and ‘Rachel’ this will look as follows:

```
  =Sumifs(column ‘time in’ from data set, column ‘name’ from dataset, “Rachel”, column ‘date’ from data set, “10/01/2017”)
```

Where Rachel and the date also can be a referenced cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(SHEET1!$A$2:$E$22)/((SHEET2!$B$1=SHEET1!$B$2:$B$22)*(SHEET2!$A4=SHEET1!$C$2:$C$22)),1)
```

The above formula will grab the row number that matches your criteria.  to pull the information you want, you can place the row number inside an INDEX formula to get the following:

```
=INDEX(SHEET1!$D:$E,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(SHEET1!$A$2:$E$22)/((SHEET2!$B$1=SHEET1!$B$2:$B$22)*(SHEET2!$A4=SHEET1!$C$2:$C$22)),1),COLUMN(A1))
```

You can place the above in your first Time cell and copy right and down.  You will see errors if criteria do not exist.  ie no person of that name or no date data for that person.  to avoid this you can wrap the whole thing in an IFERROR like the below:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(SHEET1!$D:$E,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(SHEET1!$A$2:$E$22)/((SHEET2!$B$1=SHEET1!$B$2:$B$22)*(SHEET2!$A4=SHEET1!$C$2:$C$22)),1),COLUMN(A1)),"Nothing found")
```

if you would rather a blank than nothing found display change the "nothing found" to "" or 0 if you want 0 to be displayed.

Note:  Aggregate is performing array like calculations in this case.  As such you do not want to full column references as it will cause a lot of unnecessary  calculations to be performed.  Because you have unique entries, SUMIFS option given in another answer is a much better choice.

Answer (score 0):

I think a pivot table will do the job for you.

1. Place the **employee name in the filter**, place **date** and
   **times** in the rows.
2. Remove subtotals from the Pivot Table
3. Change Table layout to tabular and Repeat rows
4. Right click on the **Time In** and select **Ungroup**

[image]

Then you have the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the following layout:

[image]

In B11 write this formula and drag down:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$E$5,MATCH($B$7&$A11,$B$2:$B$5&$C$2:$C$5,0),3)
```

In C11 write this and drag down:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$E$5,MATCH($B$7&$A11,$B$2:$B$5&$C$2:$C$5,0),4)
```

Note that these are Array-Formulas, so you need to enter them with `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER` instead of the normal `Enter`.

You will get a #NV error if the employee hasn't worked on one of the dates A11 and A12. So you could surround the Formula with `IFERROR` to avoid this.